# SED command to extract 4-digit numbers from string

Tags: regex, sed

I have a file with this output:

```
abis02 - GBS API 8085 is running abis02 - GBS API 8180 is running abis - GBS API 8181 is running
```

I want to get only the port numbers (8085, 8180, 8181), the port number can be random, and I need to extract only them.

I try using this:

```
b=$(echo $abis02 | sed 's/[^0-9]\{4\}//g')
```

but I recive this:

```
c02PI 8085[00;32sc02PI 8180[00;32sc02PI 8181[0m
```

How can I get only the port numbers?

Comment: Why do you have the `\{4\}` quantifier? That will only remove non-digits that are in groups of 4.

Comment: First try quoting your variable and see where it gets you.

Comment: Your input appears to contain terminal control escape sequences, in addition to what you showed.

Comment: It's much more efficient to do this **without** `sed`.

Comment: `b=${abis02//[![:digit:]]/}` for the general ("remove all non-digit characters") case that the original title implied.

Comment: btw, 5-digit port numbers are legal (up to 65535); might be safer to search for `{4,5}` rather than `{4}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
echo 'abis02 - GBS API 8085 is running abis02 - GBS API 8180 is running abis - GBS API 8181 is running' | grep -Eo '\b[0-9]{4}\b'
8085
8180
8181
```

Comment: Why did you add `\s` to the regex? Your result contains unnecessary spaces.

Comment: I suggest to replace both `\s` with `\b` (word boundry).

Comment: _grumbles about PCRE extensions showing up in vendors' ERE implementations, and people getting accustomed to using them despite not being standardized_

Comment: You an improve portability by using `-w` and removing the nonstandard `\b`:s.

Answer (score 3):

`sed` is not needed for this; bash's built-in string manipulation is adequate-to-task.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
string='abis02 - GBS API 8085 is running abis02 - GBS API 8180 is running abis - GBS API 8181 is running'
ports=( )

while [[ $string =~ ([[:digit:]]{4})(.*) ]]; do
    ports+=( "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" )
    string=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
done

echo "Found ports:" "${ports[@]}"
```

...properly emits as output:

```
Found ports: 8085 8180 8181
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you asked for `sed`,

```
sed -E 's/ ([0-9]{4}) /,\1,/g; s/^[^,]*,//; s/,[^,]*$//; s/,+[^0-9]+[^,]+,/,/g' file 
8085,8180,8181
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `awk` with a whitespace as record separator and line feed as the output record separator:

```sh
s='abis02 - GBS API 8085 is running abis02 - GBS API 8180 is running abis - GBS API 8181 is running'
awk 'BEGIN{RS="[[:space:]]";ORS="\n"} /^[0-9]{4}$/' <<< "$s"
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/qYbUgJ), yielding

```
8085
8180
8181
```

Only those records are output that fully match a four digit string.

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, please try following. Written and tested in GNU `grep`.

```
grep -oP '\b\d{4}\b' Input_file
```

Simple explanation would be, using GNU `grep`'s `-o` option to print only matched values. Then using `-P` option to enable PCRE regex engine. In main program matching 4 digits preceded and followed by word boundaries, to make sure to avoid partial matches.

Answer (score 1):

Another `awk` solution:

```
$ str='abis02 - GBS API 8085 is running abis02 - GBS API 8180 is running abis - GBS API 8181 is running' 
$ awk '{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if ($i ~ /[0-9]{4}/)  { print $i } } }' <<< "$str"
8085
8180
8181
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option with GNU awk is setting [FPAT](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html#Splitting-By-Content) to define the the fields are 4 digits between word boundaries, and then loop all the fields:

```
awk -v FPAT='\\<[0-9]{4}\\>' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i}' file
```

Output

```
8085
8180
8181
```